# React Native Firebase Phone Authentication null values on legit phone number

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

```js
    verify = async () => {
    this.isProcessing = true
    this.isRegistering = true
    const phoneNumber = `${this.currentUser.phoneDialCode}${this.currentUser.phoneNumber}`
    // Get reference to the currently signed-in user
    this.prevUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
    console.log('prev user', this.prevUser)
    await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(async (results) => {
        this.isProcessing = false
        this.verificationCode = results
        console.log('=================================')
        console.log('RESULTS', this.verificationCode)
        console.log('=================================')
        if (!this.verificationCode.verificationId) {
          this.triggerAlert(
            'Error',
            'Phone number might have been blocked because of too much use.',
            () => true,
          )
          await firebase.auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).then((res) => {
            console.log('ver phon', res)
          })
        }
        console.log('=================================')
        console.log('Current User', firebase.auth().currentUser)
        console.log('=================================')
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.isProcessing = false
        this.loginOldUser()
        // this.prevUser = new User()
        this.triggerAlert(
          'Error',
          'Phone number format might not be correct. Please check again.',
          () => true,
        )
        this.isPhoneVerified = false
        this.currentUser.phoneFlag = ''
        this.currentUser.phoneCode = ''
        this.currentUser.phoneDialCode = ''
        this.currentUser.phoneNumber = ''
      })
  }
```

**Logs:**
[image: Logs]

So for some reason, after using my phone number multiple times, it no longer returns proper values only null. I haven't used them for a while so I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm trying to test resending of codes, that's why I'm not using whitelisted numbers.

I added verify phone number just to see maybe it would give more insight to my problem.

Any thoughts on these? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you say:

> after using my phone number multiple times, it no longer returns proper values only null

My first thought is that you're being throttled.

From the Firebase documentation on [sending a verification code to the user's phone](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone):

> To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development, use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later.

Comment: I haven't used my number over the weekend though. It's also been like that since last week. I've used my other phone number and a co worker's they worked last week, but this week they seemed blocked as well. What's weird is, they show up in the authentication tab of firebase even though firebase returned null values.

Comment: In that case I don't know what could be going on. If you see that no texts are being sent for any users in your project, you might want to check if you're still within the usage quota for that project. If that also doesn't explain, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: If we use new numbers, we could still receive texts and all. And I doubt I've gotten 1000 in just two weeks. Thanks for the link! I didn't see they had a support link (terribly stupid of me).